# Castor-XML: field-handler for several classes

Tags: java, xml, castor

I am trying to change the Boolean to String when create a XML File.
Here are my sources.

```java
public class BooleanHandler extends GeneralizedFieldHandler {
    public BooleanHandler() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Object convertUponGet(Object value) {
        boolean booleanValue = (boolean)value;
        if(booleanValue){
            return "1";
        }else{
            return "0";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object convertUponSet(Object value) {
        if("1".equals(value)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Boolean> getFieldType() {
        return Boolean.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object newInstance(Object parent) throws IllegalStateException
    {
        //-- Since it's marked as a string...just return null,
        //-- it's not needed.
        return null;
    }
}
```

and

```
<mapping>
    <!-- Change boolean to String Value Handler-->
    <field-handler name="booleanHandler" class="test.BooleanHandler">
    </field-handler>


    <class name="test.Foo">
       <field name="testFlag" type="boolean" handler="booleanHandler">
           <bind-xml name="TEST_FLAG" node="element" />
       </field>
    </class>

    <class name="test.Bar">
       <field name="testBoolean" type="boolean" handler="booleanHandler">
           <bind-xml name="TEST_BOOLEAN" node="element" />
       </field>
    </class>
</mapping>
```

I got the exception as follows:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

It seems "field-handler" can not be used by several classes, it works if I 
put "test.MailBooleanHandler" in the "field" directly instead of "field-handler". For example:

```
<field name="testFlag" type="boolean" handler="test.BooleanHandler">
```

Is there any other way that I can use "field-handler"?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by referring to the following document.

http://castor-data-binding.github.io/castor/reference-guides/1.3.3/html/XML%20data%20binding.html#xml.field.handler.generalized
[1.7.5. Reuse a ConfigurableFieldHandler for more than one field definition]

Implement the ClonableFieldHandlerMarker interface and implement the copyFieldHandler() method will fix the issue.